# SiteCat eVar/prop missing in reports even though can see in Charles

Tags: adobe, adobe-analytics

Would appreciate any pointers in the right direction for this. I have a JS function that tracks page views (s.t()). I can see all of the data correctly firing out to charles but the client is only getting partial data in sitecat. Within this same method an s.prop2 with a text value will get reported but an s.eVar2 with the same text value as s.prop1 does not.

The client has confirmed that the eVars have all been set to enabled and type = text value.

Would anyone know why the client would only be getting partial data like this?

Many thanks!
B.

Comment: Not enough information.  Please detail what all of the settings for the eVar are, not just **Type** and **Status**.

Comment: Hi @CrayonViolent thanks for responding! I don't have access to the clients account that's the issue. Are there questions that i can ask them to provide more info? Thanks!

Comment: Well.. yes. You can ask them what the other settings for the eVar are. There's like a dozen settings for a given eVar and half of them affect how data is recorded/reported...